# c++ dll for FoxPro

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, delphi-2007, visual-foxpro

I have program compiled with FoxPro that calls d1.dll functions. d1.dll was developed with Delphi 2007. I need to develop d1.dll that will replace existing one using c++. After several tests FoxPro application crashes in random places with random messages like:

> Fatal error: Exception code=C0000005 @ 2012.12.12 11:33. Error log
>   file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VFP\vfp9rerr.log

or

> No enaugh memory execute some_function

I have removed all code from c++ dll and left just some test values that original dll usually returns. But this does't helps. Probably something is wrong with declaration and variable usage.

I have build Fox Pro small test program according to manner of declaring d1.dll function in main Fox Pro program. Unfortunately it doesn't crash. I run it from IDE while mine program runs from executable, but I don't think this is reason. Probably there is som issuersregarding variable usage.

What might be problem?

Function declaration in Delphi and C++:

C++

> extern "C" int _stdcall f1(unsigned char *aError)
>
> extern "C" int_stdcall f2(char *txt,unsigned char *aError)
>
> extern "C" int _stdcall f3(unsigned char *aError, char *aAnswer)
>
> extern "C" int _stdcall f4(unsigned char *aError)
>
> extern "C" int _stdcall f5(
>                       char* descriptor,
>                       char x,
>                       double pr,
>             char *aError,
>                       double qtity,
>                       char* kd,
>                       char* pd  )  extern "C" int _stdcall f6(char *acomment_string, unsigned char* aError)
>
> extern "C" int _stdcall f7(unsigned char tender_number, double amount,
>   unsigned char *aError)
>
> extern "C" int _stdcall f8(unsigned char *aError)

DELPHI 2007

> function f1(var aError: byte):bool; stdcall; 
>                            function f2(txt: pchar; var aError: byte):bool; stdcall;
>
> function f3(var aError: byte; adata: pchar):bool; stdcall;
>
> function f4(var aError: byte):bool; stdcall;
>
> function f5(descriptor: pchar;x: byte; pr: double; var aError: byte ;
>   qtity: double; kd : pchar ; pd: pchar  ):bool; stdcall;
>
> function f6(non_fiscal_string: pchar; var aError: byte):bool; stdcall;
>
> function f7(tender_number:byte; amount:double; var aError: byte):bool;
>   stdcall;
>
> function f8 (var aError: byte):bool; stdcall;

FoxPro test program

FoxPro
FoxPro

> declare integer f1 in c:\d1.dll string err
>
> declare integer f2 in c:\d1.dll string txt,string err
>
> declare integer f3 in c:\d1.dll string err, string rec_nr
>
> declare integer f4 in c:\d1.dll string err
>
> declare integer f5 in c:\d1.dll string descr, integer x, double pr
>   ,string err, double qty, string kd, string pd
>
> declare integer f6 in c:\d1.dll string non_fiscal_string,string err
>
> declare integer f7 in c:\d1.dll integer tender, double amount ,string
>   err
>
> declare integer f8 in c:\d1.dll string err
>
> aLength=2048
>
> aCardinal=4
>
> ff_log=space(aLength)
>
> rec_nr=SPACE(aCardinal)
>
> fiscal_rec_nr=SPACE(aCardinal)
>
> serial_nr = SPACE(aLength)
>
> status_bytes=SPACE(aCardinal)
>
> descr = "descr"
>
> x =1 pr = 123 t=0 t= f2(descr,@kl)
>
> t= f1(@kl)
>
> ```
>   Thisform.text1.Value=ff_log
> ```
>
> t= f2(descr,@kl)
>
> t= f4(@kl)
>
> ```
>   t=f3(@kl,@ff_log)
>
>   t=GetStatus(@kl,rec_nr,fiscal_rec_nr,serial_nr,status_bytes)
> ```
>
> t= f5(descr,x,pr,@kl, 1, "","")
>
> t= f2(descr,@kl)
>
> t= f2(descr,@kl)
>
> t=f6(descr,@kl)
>
> t=f8(@kl)
>
> t=f7(1,100,@kl)

Comment: When quoting error messages always paste the literal text, don't rewrite from memory. You never know what you may be leaving behind (and it also saves you from embarrassing typos.)

Comment: -1 You must fix the formatting. Use code blocks rather than quotes. Note the italics in the question at the moment. Those are not what you intend I am sure. Also, how do you expect us to debug this? We can't see any of the code!!

Answer (score 1):

1) edit question - add the TAG with your delphi version. it is not only polite but might be critical here.

2) you see "string" references in FoxPro code - that probably means your `char*` hear is C-string (aka ASCIIZ string, aka zero-terminated strings)

They need kinda special treatment. Try passing them as PAnsiChar - like - `function f1(const aError: PAnsiChar):bool; stdcall;`

Read help about Delphi PChar type - but always use `PAnsiChar` in fixed DLL API: PChar is ambiguous in different Delphi versions - mapped to either PAnsiChar or PWideChar

3) return correct datatype. Not bool.

declare **integer f2** in c:\d1.dll string txt, string err
extern "C" **int** _stdcall **f2**(char *txt,unsigned char *aError)
function **f2**(const txt, aError: PAnsiChar): **integer**; stdcall;

Comment: There is no need to change something in Delphi code. Crashes dll that is done with Visual c++

Comment: well, then do the reverse conversion!

`var x: byte` would stand for by-ref `unsigned char& x`; Bool is some windows boolean type - search it on docwiki.embarcadero.com and use proper windows type. And your FoxPro code seems inconsistent with Delphi code - there are strings where Delphi code does not have them. Only PChar aka PAnsiChar is string. not char& type

Comment: You should also configure VC++ to make non-Unicode library, so it would have 1-byte char, not 2-bytes char

Comment: @Arioch'The No, you've got that wrong in your latest comment. On Windows, `char` is always just a single 8 bit byte. The 16 bit character type is `wchar_t`.

Comment: @David there should be some correspondence to _T macro - the type that would be either single byte or two bytes depending on project settings

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, there is the `TCHAR` stuff, but the code here is `char`.